# Magento child theme overriden by custom theme on categories pages

Tags: css, magento

I'm having trouble adapting a Magento Theme.

I'm using a child theme of a custom theme in order to be able to update this theme in the future. It has worked fine in home page and product pages linked from this page, but when I enter a category page and from there go to a product page, my child theme is not applied anymore (custom theme instead).

I tried a lot of things but oddly, no changes were visible. I even commented a css I was importing from the custom css style field in the admin, and it was still being applied. I flushed cache of course, but no results.

I must say that originally I had a folder with css inside the main theme default folder (magma/default/child_theme/css/style.css) and it was linked in the field as mentioned above. Then I made a copy of it and put it in magma/child_theme/css/style.css, which is the way a child theme must be, as I understand. I changed a color in this new css and no changes made. The first css is still being called. I don't know from where, since I commented the import, as I said.

Any idea where to look into?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned it's specifically categories and their products.  I would check `Catalog > Manage Categories` then, specifically the `Custom Design` tab on whatever category/categories are giving you trouble.

Comment: Thanks! It seems it was a matter of bad subtheming. I did it the proper way, with local.xml file importing instead of an @import in the custom css field (admin). The problem was that the categories pages called that same css, and obviously the relative url was not the same as the home page. Now I understand more about Magento theming!